# Converting svg to pdf with Batik not working on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: pdf, svg, batik, ubuntu-11.10

I am attempting to convert a svg image to pdf using the Batik SVG toolkit on Ubuntu-11.10.
I have Batik 1.7 and Fop 0.95 installed. When running the following in the terminal:

```
java -jar /usr/java/share/batik-rasterizer.jar -m application/pdf /home/user/Batik_Test/colors.svg  
-scriptSecurityOff
```

I get the following error:

*Error while converting files:
  Error: cannot access transcoder for image of type application/pdf*

The one thing I did notice was that the file **'pdf-transcoders.jar'** was not on the machine so I added that to /usr/share/java on the off chance that was the problem but that did not make a difference.

I would appreciate any help from anyone out there with experience using Batik on ubuntu. What am I missing?

-J

Answer (score 1):

if you have the *java* executable **batik-rasterizer.jar** in **/usr/java/share/** directory, you can create a dir named **lib** in this same path (**/usr/java/share/**)

so to have

**/usr/java/share/lib**

in this latest dir (**lib**) you will copy the **pdf-transcoder.jar** so to have

**/usr/java/share/lib/pdf-transcoder.jar**

anyway, you need also other *libs* in addition to this, so, it is better for you, copy the **whole content** of **lib** directory contained in batik binary distribution zip file

- http://mirror.nohup.it/apache//xmlgraphics/batik/batik-1.7.zip

to

**/usr/java/share/lib/**

only ****content****, not **lib**, if you want copy the **whole lib** at once, you need to put in

**/usr/java/share/**

Comment: Thanks Dingo! I'll give that a try and let you know how it works.

Comment: OK, My copy of batik-rasterizer.jar is in /usr/share/java so I added a  folder there titled 'lib' and put all the files from lib in batik1.7 but I still get the same error.

Comment: please, unzip this file you have downloaded (http://mirror.nohup.it/apache//xmlgraphics/batik/batik-1.7.zip) and run batik-rasterizer from this same folder. I used successfully in this way

Comment: +1 This is the correct solution. I had much the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04. The packages from the repositories inexplicably don't work (just for PDF in my case, but did work for PNG, JPEG etc), but I downloaded direct from apache and referenced their jar file and it worked for all formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing Batik from fedora using the .jar file it is quite painful due to the java ignoring the -classpath flag. I assume batik in /usr/share/java Select the location according to your system One solution could be the following: create a scratch directory (I assume you are superuser, anyway you always can sudo commands)

```sh
mkdir scratch
cd scratch
jar -xf /usr/share/java/batik-rasterizer.jar
```

This output the content of the jar file into scratch, then create a MANIFEST.MF file or take the output one from the dump

```sh
cp META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .
```

Now edit the MANIFEST.MF file (I like to use vi, anyone use their preferred one)

```sh
vi MANIFEST.MF
```

Add a Class-Path: line into the MANIFEST.MF as for example:

```sh
Class-Path: batik-all.jar xmlgraphics-commons.jar xml-commons-apis-ext.jar pdf-transcoder.jar avalon-framework.jar avalon-framework-api.jar apache-commons-logging.jar apache-commons-io.jar
```

Then close the file and recreate the jar file

```sh
jar cmf MANIFEST.MF /usr/share/java/batik-rasterizer.jar org/*
```

Include all jar that batik has nested classes

Then you can use it!

```sh
java -jar /usr/share/java/batik-rasterizer.jar -scriptSecurittyOff -m image/png -d image.png image.svg
```

for example, and that's it!