# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMDocument

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

Following up many many questions and answers to use BATIK, I'm having trouble of fixing my error and I couldn't find anything that might help. And  this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171682/grails-2-3-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-batik-dom-svg-svgomdocumen) has no answer.

My problem is when I download the pdf on my application, the error occur(I even tried to include the jar):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMDocument
```

In my jasper report I have this included:

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="453" y="117" width="246" height="115"/>
        <imageExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable"><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstance(new java.io.File("C:\\Project\\myProject\\web-app\\images\\tomcat.svg"))]]>
        </imageExpression>
</image>
```

Basically, my BuildConfig.groovy is like this:

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes 'xml-apis', 'xml-apis-ext', 'xercesImpl'
}
```

and my dependencies:

```
compile("org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:0.94",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-codec:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-js:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:1.7",
        "org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:1.2",
        "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4",
        "org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:4.3.1",
        "org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:4.3.1",
        "xalan:xalan:2.6.0",
        "xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:1.3.04"
){
transitive = false
```

Why I can't download? Invalid svg? I got [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Tomcat-logo.svg) svg from wiki.

Comment: Hello, Trying to clean up unanswered. Did you solve this? Maybe you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good/bad answer nor a fix, but it only runs at `grails run-war`, I don't know why and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your deployed code on either the presence of batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar or batik-all-1.7.jar (using that would shorten your compile configuration considerably too). If it is missing, add it manually just to see if that fixes your issue. If it is missing however something is missing in your deploy configuration.

Comment: Already tried adding thoses jars. still the same error. and inside of my war, the jar is there.

Comment: Java version on the server the same as on your development machine? And what JVM are you using?

Comment: Yes, both with java 1.7.45 ish